# The type initialize for 'emgu.cv.invoke' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, emgucv

Currently I'm facing this issue on windows 10 pro operating system.

Comment: I think you forgot to include your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, in addition to the Emgu.CV package, you must also install the [Emgu.CV.runtime.windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.runtime.windows/4.5.1.4349/ReportAbuse) package.